# How insert a list of optional texts at the position of cursor using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How insert a list of optional texts at the position of cursor using jquery?

For example, I have this ul li list

aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj

Now i need to insert each highlighted list item at the position of cursor..

An example of the following text in a textarea shows only list items change when selecting them from the ul li list at the position of the cursor.

This is an insertion test of aaa
                             bbb
                             ccc
                             ddd
                             eee

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking; do you want to change the text that is in the textarea when items in your ul li list are selected?

Comment: Yes Jasper, I want to change the text at the current cursor position to any of the selected items in the list

Answer (score 0):

Question is not entirely clear but I assume you are talking about an AutoComplete plugin.
You can use the one that is part of jQuery UI:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/